# wkhtmltopdf via proc_open() does not work in Apache's PHP module

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf, proc-open

I'm converting HTML documents to PDF by invocating [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) with [proc_open()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php).

Here is an example script:

```php
$wkhtmltopdf = '/bin/wkhtmltopdf';

$html = '<html><body><h1>Hello world!</h1></body></html>';

$process = proc_open($wkhtmltopdf . ' - -', [
    0 => ['pipe', 'r'],
    1 => ['pipe', 'w'],
    2 => ['pipe', 'w']
], $pipes);

fwrite($pipes[0], $html);
fclose($pipes[0]);

$pdf = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
fclose($pipes[1]);

$err = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
fclose($pipes[2]);

$status = proc_close($process);

if ($status != 0) {
    die('Status ' . $status . ': ' . var_export($err, true));
}

echo substr($pdf, 0, 4);
```

If I run the script from the PHP CLI, the script works fine, and outputs the PDF header as expected:

```
%PDF
```

If however, I run it from Apache's PHP module, I always get the same error:

> Status 134: ''

Googling status 134 gives something like "assertion failed", which does not help me much. `stderr` being empty, it's not helpful either.

**Why doesn't this code run under Apache's PHP module?**

I'm using `wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3` under Fedora 25, with PHP 7.1.

Comment: Does it really work from the CLI, or just from CLI with X11 running? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38719715/the-exit-status-code-134-says-something-went-wrong // Exit code 134 usually corresponds to SIGABRT, btw. -- Also the `error.log` might be more relevant, if stderr yields nothing.

Comment: Hmm you're right, I'm using the CLI in a graphical environment. If I try via SSH, I now get the following error: *Error 134: 'QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display*. Is there a way to make it work in this case?

Comment: Like my grandmother used to say: compile from source or GTFO. Your wkhtmltopdf binary is unsuitable for server use without workarounds.

Comment: On the server where it's working on PHP-FPM, the version is `wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.1 (with patched qt)`. Do you think the `patched qt` thing is what makes it work without X11 running?

Comment: OK, I finally downloaded the archive from the [official wkhtmltopdf download page](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html), and this archive contains a compiled binary version that works out of the box. I uninstalled the version that comes with Fedora 25 and replaced it with this one, and it works like a charm. Thanks for your help! Note that the solutions in the question you linked to involve working around with `xvfb`, but none of the proposed solutions seemed directly applicable to Fedora (no package with this name exists).

Comment: Stupid close... -.-'